# Python Socket Binding : Retry until Socket/Port is available and not in use anymore

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I'm facing an issue with creating python sockets. Once I close a Socket using **close()**, and retry to **socket.bind()** to the same port, i get `OSError : 98 Address already in use` even though the port is not used (double checking with `netstat -nlp | grep port`). I understand that is due to the TIME_WAIT of a TCP socket or hang time, as the socket binds after few minutes.

Is there any way to **loop** the python program to **keep trying to bind to that port** until it becomes **available**, **instead of exiting** the program right away.?

Thankyou in advance

Paul Pavish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `catch` the exception that is being thrown and retry to bind in a loop.
For example:

```
bound = False
while not bound:
    try:
        s.bind((address, port))
        bound = True
    except OSError:
        print("Failed to bind, trying again in 5 seconds...")
        time.sleep(5)
```